# Add columns of 2 dimentional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an JavaScript array:

```
var arr = {[a, 1], [b, 2], [a, 4], [a, 5]};
```

I want final array to look like:

```
var final = {[a, 10], [b, 2]};
```

The final array is formed by adding up 2nd element of 2 dimensional array when the 1st element matches.
Please advice how can this be achieved in JavaScript

Comment: It is not an array..It's `object`

Comment: it is not an object.. Its' `unexpected token ,`

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Are `a` and `b` variables or strings?

Comment: @kab: If you don't respond here, don't expect any answers. As it is, this question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for responding late

Comment: You got your syntax backwards, you need to start with `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {a: 4}, {a: 5}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that the first item of the array a string and the outer most array is wrapped with a square bracket, which means that your input should look like this.

```
var arr = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 4], ["a", 5]];

var mergeItem = function(list) {
  var map = {};
  for(var i = 0 ; i < list.length; i ++){
    var currentItem = list[i];
    if(!map[currentItem[0]]){
      map[currentItem[0]] = 0;
    }
    map[currentItem[0]] += currentItem[1];
  }

  var result = [];
  var keys = Object.keys(map);
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i ++ ){
    result.push([keys[i], map[keys[i]]]);
  }
  return result;
}

mergeItem(arr);
```

Comment: For my array if the elements as shown below [["A",["05",90]],["A",["04",240]],["A",["03",235]]] ,How to form a final array like ["A",[["05",90],["04",240],["03",235]]] .Please advice